# Help! Set up bad permissions for a list know I am locked out of changing the list permissions

Tags: list, permissions, custom-list

Help!

So I added "Stop Inheriting Permissions" to a list then I set up a bad permission for that list and now I can't change permissions because I don't have permission to do that. How can I reset permissions on that list?

Answer (score 1):

ask someone who has permission to the site or the site collection administrator. There is no other way

Answer (score 0):

Ask to someone who has higher permissions on the site.
Or if you can access to the centra admin, set you as site collection administrator for that site.

Answer (score 0):

User with Site Collection Permission will be able to grant you back your lost permissions.